# Time of execution of a code on matlab

Tags: matlab

To compare the time of execution of two functions, i wrote a code where i measure the time elapsed for each function and for each index ( with the command clock /etime). However, on my computer the first function is faster than the second, and on an other computer, it's the opposite. ( I tried several time with different indexes and with clearing for each time the data ,but it is still the same result).

Can you explain me why there is such difference?

---

**EDIT**

I edited my question to show more details.
I wanted to compare execution time for a convolution ( optimized code) vs fft.
The first code is conv2fft ( I found it on internet . It's  based on mex code).
The second one is calculation of fft. Here is the second code :

```
     function xcorr_ab = freqxcorr(T,A)
T_size = size(T);
A_size = size(A);
outsize = A_size + T_size - 1;
% calculate correlation in frequency domain
Fa = fft2(rot90(T,2),outsize(1),outsize(2));
Fb = fft2(A,outsize(1),outsize(2));
xcorr_ab = ifft2(Fa .* Fb,'symmetric');
end
```

The code to compare their speed is :

```
 T=rand (800,1280);
j=1;
profile on;
for i=2:0.5:12
    ii=i*10;
    C{j}=rand(ii,ii);
    conv2fft(C{j},T);
    freqxcorr(C{j},T);  
    j=j+1;
  end
  profile viewer;
```

On the first computer ( matlab r2017a ,a fast computer), the profiler shows :
[profiler on the first computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIRRm.jpg)

On the second one ( slow computer , matlab r2017a ):
[profiler on the second computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE521.jpg)

It's normal that on the second computer , it will be slower, but it found strange that the fastest function isn't the same on the two computers.

I want also to mention that even if i test with rand matrix's, sometimes, i save the data to compare between the same inputs, but it still the same result.

Comment: Execution time depends on a lot of things: Matlab version, amount of RAM available, operating system... For example, loops seem to [have been made faster](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/) in recent Matlab versions, thanks to changes in JIT compilation. Also, you should use the [`timeit`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) function for accurate timing

Comment: @luis-mendo on both of computers matlab version is r2017a, how can i know which  compiler is used in each one ?

Comment: That depends on the Matlab version, so that factor at least is common. But there's also RAM, processor, cache memories, OS; lots of factors. Also, as I said, `clock` and `etime` may be less reilable than `timeit`

Comment: @luis-mendo  MinGW 4.9.2 compiler is slower than Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch your code performance with

```
profile on; 
myFunction(); 
profile viewer;
```